# Bash script stops after executing PHP script 8 times

Tags: php, bash

I have a bash script which is executing php script. My bash knowledge is poor and I need to execute that PHP script about hundred times. I simply copy pasted the execute line:

```
#!/bin/bash
php /home/me/public_html/script/stats.php 1 2 3
php /home/me/public_html/script/stats.php 1 2 3
php /home/me/public_html/script/stats.php 1 2 3
...
```

1,2,3 are arguments i pass to php script.

All works fine, but after 8-th line bash script hangs not going into executing next. So I have to restart it again.

What can be wrong?

**UPD**

PHP (not full script but general idea)

It starts with retrieving command line args. Passes them to a function which uses them in a msql query. Every result of the msql query is passed to another function which uses that result to form up an url from which it retrieves a comma delimited string and processes it splitting it into array and inserting into another table. After main function completes the msql link is closed, script exits.

```
<?php
if (($argv[1] > 0) && ($argv[2] > 0) && ($argv[3] > 0)) {
echo "All good! Here we go: ";
echo "\n";
gatherstats($argv[1],$argv[2],$argv[3]);

} else {
echo "no\n";

}



function gatherstats($y,$m,$cl){ 

  Require 'db.php';
// SQL QUERY HERE AND A LOOP TO PROCESS RESULTS

//CALLS UP NEXT FUNCTION FOR EACH RESULT
 crawl($a,$b,$c);

}

function crawl($atr,$year,$month) { 

       //forms up specific url from passed vars and processes it

    }


  mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: Maybe pass a fourth argument, `100`, and just do one call

Comment: Check using `ps -ef` how.many instances of PHP are alive at the end

Comment: @Esailija :) nope:) 1,2,3 are different per line. but their value doesn't influence the stop of the execution. I mixed them few times and replaced - still same result.

@Cthulhu `ps -ef` give no alive php instances after the stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the 8th php script call hangs for some reason. You can do this to avoid typing the command 100 times:

```
for i in {1..100}; do
   php /home/me/public_html/script/stats.php 1 2 3 > some_log_file_$i.log
done
```

Add some print statements to the php script and check the log for the 8 call to see what happened. If the requirement is not to stop the calls (even if one fails), then you can make the script calls asynchronous using

```
for i in {1..100}; do
   php /home/me/public_html/script/stats.php 1 2 3 > some_log_file_$i.log &
done
```

Comment: Great! thanks for the loop suggestion. About the printouts from PHP - they do exist. since there are also loops inside php i echo the completion of each loop cycle. All seems good. no error, nothing, just as soon as 8-th execution is complete = bash hangs:(

Comment: Check out the comment of @Cthulhu, an look for alive instances of php after the 8 call. Can you post the php code?

Comment: Cthulhu comment didn't help much unfortunately. Added php script to the post.

Comment: Can you add an `echo` statement after the `gatherstats` invocation and test again?